# How many rails models do I need for a picture upload with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, rails-activerecord

I struggle with understanding the mvc of rails.

My goal is a simple site with an upload option, implemented by carrierwave.
I want this for my wedding so guests may give me their pictures with no hussle of logging in or whatsoever and since I have my own rails server running I can get them by ftp later.

All examples I could find work with two models: gallery and pictures.

But I will never have multiple galleries, but multiple uploads at most.

So, my question is highly theoretical:

*do I need two models for ActiveRecord to deal with the pictures,
or is one model enough to handle the pictures as instances of the class "Photo"?*

**Thank you very much** for pointing me in direction of good code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need one model: `Picture` Since you have just one gallery, you don't need to make that a model. That would simply be a view of all the `Pictures` in the database. And then your controller would have three actions:

- `index` - Lists all the `Pictures` in the database.
- `new` - Presents a screen to upload a new `Picture`
- `create` - Handles the actual uploading of the new `Picture`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented it with carrierwave and for multiple files with plupload: [Blogged about it](http://dontyoudarenottobeaware.blogspot.de/2013/03/rails-carrierwavve-plupload-multiple.html)